# How to make parameters of a forRoot Method to be Optional?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am providing a config required for my service in my lib via `forRoot`.
I want this library to be used with default config, if consuming app doesn't want. I tried using `@Optional`, but doesn't work.

Here is my sample module

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, HttpClientModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, RouterModule],
    declarations: [MyComponent],
    exports: [MyComponent]
})
export class MyModule {
  // Configure url, clientid & other for widget specific configuration
  public static forRoot(@Optional() options: Config): ModuleWithProviders {
    if (!options) {
      options = { url: 'default-url', otherparams: []};
    }
    return { ngModule: MyModule, providers: [MyService, {provide: Config, useValue: options} ]};
  }
```

This code doesn't work when I use it like this in consuming app

```
MyModule.forRoot()
```

It gives me error:

> arguments 0 instead of 1.

Is it even possible to make params optional? If yes, How?

Is there a better way to accept config from consuming app (except input for components)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Optional` is only used when a DI mechanism wants to inject a service. You can use it only in the constructors. If you have a parameter which must be an optional you can use `?` optional parameter.

```
public static forRoot(options?: Config): ModuleWithProviders {

    if (!options) {
       options = { url: 'default-url', otherparams: []};
    }

    return { ngModule: MyModule, providers: [MyService, {provide: Config, useValue: options} ]};

}
```

And you can call it `MyModule.forRoot()` - with no parameters.